# Pegar valor de uma li angularjs ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic

```
<div class="list">
<li class="item" ng-click="city()" ng-repeat="seg in segmento">{{seg}}</li>
</div>
```

Eu tenho este codigo no meu framework ionic eu gostaria de pegar o valor da li eu ja tentei com name, ng-model alguem tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Passa seu segmento por parâmetro para a função city. Ex; city(seg)

Comment: Pq tu não pega os dados direto do array "segmento" ? é mais fácil.

Comment: eu pensei em passar pelo parâmetro, mas é que dps eu vou ter que pegar esse valor novamente.

Comment: Não da pra pegar pelo array segmento, porque essa lista tem um click eu quero o valor que o usuário clicar no caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="list">
<li class="item" ng-click="city(seg)" ng-repeat="seg in segmento">{{seg}}</li>
</div>
```

O `seg` é o elemento selecionado, você pode passar por parâmetro.